# Service Stack IRequiresHttpRequest Pattern

Tags: servicestack

How does this work?  I've read the docs but am hoping for some more info.

From reading the docs I understand that when my DTO implements IRequiresHttpRequest, then the DTO's properties will not get automatically populated, but in my DTO I now have access to the HttpRequest object so I can change my DTO to have 'get' properties that pull things from the request object.

What is meant to inject the HttpRequest into my DTO?  The docs suggest that service stack does this behind the scenes, however I can only get it to work if I register a custom request binder and manually inject the HttpRequest object.

```
RequestBinders.Add(typeof(MyDto), httpReq => { 
    var dto = new MyDto(); 
    dto.HttpRequest = httpReq;
    return dto;
});
```

Question 1:  How exactly is the injection for IRequiresHttpRequest meant to work?

Question 2:  Is there a way to gain access to the HttpRequest object so that my DTO can support custom 'get' properties, by still have service stack run it automatic mapping?  For example:

```
public class MyDto
    : IRequiresHttpRequest
{
    public Int32 AutoMappedProperty1 { get; set; }
    public Int32 AutoMappedProperty2 { get; set; }
    public Int32 AutoMappedProperty3 { get; set; }
    public Int32 AutoMappedProperty4 { get; set; }

    public Int32 CustomMappedProperty { get { return customMappedProperty; } }

    IHttpRequest httpRequest;

    public IHttpRequest HttpRequest
    {
        get
        {
            return httpRequest;
        }
        set
        {
            httpRequest = value;

            // lets say this searches the query string for a variety of 
            // different keys, and then maps one of them of 
            // CustomMappedProperty based upon a specific set of rules
            customMappedProperty = [...]
        }
    }
}
```

In the case above I am defining how CustomMappedProperty gets populated, but I still want service stack to go ahead and map all of the 'set'-able properties.  Is there a way to achieve this?  Can I manually invoke the service stack dto mapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which docs did you read about `IRequiresHttpRequest`? IRequiresHttpRequest works the same as `IRequiresRequestContext` which is only for decorating on **Services** and **Validators** to tell ServiceStack that it requires access and to inject the current IHttpRequest or IRequestContext.

The [Custom Serialization / Deserialization wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) only mentions that `IRequiresRequestStream` and `IRequiresSoapMessage` can be used on **Request DTOs** to signal to ServiceStack to skip processing the Request body and allow you to manually deserialize the request yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Access-HTTP-specific-features-in-services

Comment: that page only mentions IRequiresRequestContext, I must have assumed that IRequiresHttpRequest would be injected in the same way...

Comment: ok but that talks about injecting the Request Contexts in your service, not for Request DTOs and skipping deserialization. My answer explains the differences.

Comment: oh i see, i misunderstood, i thought the interface was for dtos

Comment: So if i want generate a dto with some specific stuff from the HttpRequest and then have ServiceStack automap the rest, is that possible?  What is the recommended why to achieve what I am trying to do.  Ty for the help :D

Comment: If you take over the request binding, by definition it's up to you to bind and populate the request. If you just want to access additional info not mapped then access it from `base.Request` inside your service.

Comment: Thanks!  I take it that that is done so by having a service that implements IRequiresHttpRequest?

Comment: Everything already exists when inheriting from the default [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs) class.